# How much power can a MacBook Pro output through the 3.5mm jack?

Tags: audio, macbook, macbook-pro, headphones

I have a MacBook Pro (13" model from early 2020 with four ports) and often I will plug my WH-1000XM4 over ear headset into the 3.5mm jack. A couple times I've had the volume accidentally go to max in which one can hear distortion and it is ridiculously loud.

How much power does the MacBook Pro audio jack output and is it enough to damage my headphones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

16 watt at peak
Which probably most headphones can't reach so no danger
Sony's thought of this and if that starts happening what's the difference between these and some knocked up Chinese ones.
I have the same pair and I measured 10.6 at full volume of mac and 200 percent volume in vlc using a FLAC file

Comment: That is super helpful. Thanks!